# How to choose the IP address to use when sending an HTTP request?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I am using a machine with multiple IPv6 address on the network interface.
How can I choose from which IP address I am sending the HTTP request I am making to a remote server if each of them can be routed to it?

Comment: Use your firewall, which are you using?

Comment: You mean iptable PREROUTING and POSTROUTING for instance?